# PowerShell script to make azure container readonly

Tags: powershell, azure-blob-storage

We have a requirement where, while deployment is going on, azure container/blobs should not be accessable.
I need to write powershell script to make azure container/blobs not accessable for some time and then again set it to pervious state after some time. This is to maintain integrity of data.
can anyone help on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `Set-AzureStorageContainerAcl` cmdlet.

```
Set-AzureStorageContainerAcl -Container [container name] -Permission off -PassThru
```

See

`Get-Help Set-AzureStorageContainerAcl` for full usage / examples

Comment: This is helpful. Can we also make container readonly(but not  writable and updatable).